# Which namespaces are used in the Prism 6 for regions?

Tags: c#, prism, windows-10, uwp

Which namespaces need to specify controls in the views that I want to use as the placeholder regions?

In Prism 5, how written in internet, it was necessary to specify

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions; assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition"
```

and use something like this:

```
<ItemsControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="CustomerRegion"/>
```

And what namespace specified in Prism 6?

With `xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"`  doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Since Prism 6 is not a microsoft patterns and practices project anymore.  In the release notes for version 6

Namespaces

Removed Microsoft.Practices from all namespaces (breaking)

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes---6.0.0

I would try this instead

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Prism.Regions; assembly=Prism.Composition"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this namespace:

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
```

See this sample:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/HelloWorld

Comment: Errors:

The attachable property 'RegionName' was not found in type 'RegionManager'.

Unknown attachable member 'RegionManager.RegionName' on element 'ItemsControl'

Comment: What packages have you added to your project?  You must have Prism.Core, Prism.Wpf, and a container such as Prism.Unity.  You must be missing Prism.Wpf because that is the assembly in which regions exist.

Comment: I have Prism.Core, Prism Windows and Prism.Unity.

NuGet say Prism.Wpf 6.1.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0
How to use regions in UWP?

Comment: Ahhh...  There is some confusion on your targeted platform.  Regions are not supported in Prism for UWP.  Only Prism for WPF.  If you are writing UWP apps, you don't have regions yet.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Will look for other opportunities.